# Chrome Extension Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make life a lot easier in doing a manual task a lot faster using a bit of javascript, however I'd now like to incorporate the same code into a Chrome extension but I'm struggling to get it working.

Here's what I  have at the moment

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Keyword Wrapper",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Keyword Wrapper.",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png",
    "popup.js"
]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        width: 350px;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        font: 20px normal helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and popup.js

```
function Wrapmsg() {
var message = document.createTextNode("Wrapped!");
var out = document.createElement("div");
out.appendChild(message);
document.body.appendChild(out);
}
window.onload = Wrapmsg;

(function(){var box_list = $$('.gwt-TextBox');for(var     i=0;i<box_list.length;i++){ box_list[i].value='"'+box_list[i].value+'"';}})();
undefined}
```

The aim is essentially to wrap the text in text boxes of a page in double quotes and show a pop up message saying Wrapped!

Any idea where I am going wrong?

T

Comment: Error I have is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }      popup.js:11`

Comment: @TMAC, Check the syntax. Pay attention on symbols `{ } , ; ( )`.

Comment: @TMAC, why did you write it: `undefined}` ?

Comment: have removed undefined}, now have the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined`

Comment: Hi, removed both $$ and undefined, and now receive an undefined error `function Wrapmsg() {
    var message = document.createTextNode("Wrapped!");
    var out = document.createElement("div");
    out.appendChild(message);
    document.body.appendChild(out);
}
window.onload = Wrapmsg;

(function(){
    var box_list = ('.gwt-TextBox');
    for(var i=0; i < box_list.length; i++) { 
        box_list[i].value = '"' + box_list[i].value + '"';
    }
})();`